# Magnifying glass UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, arkit

Trying to add a magnifying-glass effect to a uiview, but the magnfifying glass is always black.

My code for the Magnifing glass view:

```
public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    context.translateBy(x: self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    context.scaleBy(x: self.scale, y: self.scale)
    self.viewToMagnify.layer.render(in: context)
}
```

And in the View-to-Magnify:

```
self.magnifiedView = MagnifiedView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
self.magnifiedView.viewToMagnify = self.view
self.view.addSubview(magnifiedView)
```

**Edit:**
I want to use it in an ARSession on the camera output. The code above works fine for a UIImageView. Updating the View of the camera output in real-time seems to make some problems.

Comment: Did you solved it ?